# AgGrid Updating to v19, what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

i'm updating my Ag-grid version of my angular(5+) app to the version 19.

Right now, I check the [basic guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/) of the official web page, but when i'm trying to compile my app with the following command: `ng build --prod --build-optimizer --output-hashing all` didn't works and the console is show me the following output: [image], the information on the internet regarding this is quite small, not to say null, I think that because it is a recent version. Another info that i can provide is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "multiapp-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open --extract-css=true",
    "build": "ng build --prod --build-optimizer --output-hashing all",
    "build:all": "run-s build:client build:aot",
    "build:client": "ng build -prod --build-optimizer --app 0",
    "build:aot": "ng build --aot --app 1",
    "build:server": "webpack -p",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^0.6.8",
    "@angular-material-extensions/password-strength": "^3.0.0",
    "@angular-redux/store": "^6.5.7",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "5.0.0-beta.13",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/service-worker": "5.2.11",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "1.2.0",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^5.0.0",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/d3": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.0",
    "ag-grid": "^18.1.2",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^19.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^19.0.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^19.0.0",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.24.1",
    "angular-split": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "angular2-grid": "^2.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "d3": "^5.5.0",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "js-search": "^1.4.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^4.5.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.8.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.111",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2"
  }
}
```

That is everything that i have, as a extra info.
I tried to made that installation from a fresh project of angular without any problems, so i think to is a problem, in my application.

Comment: wwhatt? ag-grid v 19 is released? officially? https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/

Comment: @Paritosh check here: https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-changelog/?fixVersion=19.0.0 seems that they forgot to update `pipeline` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free version of ag-Grid was renamed to ag-grid-community in version 19.

You need to rename references of "ag-grid" to "ag-grid-community":

```
"ag-grid-angular": "^19.0.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^19.0.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "^19.0.0",
```

You'll replace "ag-grid" with "ag-grid-community" - you don't need both.